# How can I make ${extensionPath} work in Vscode

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I got two pictures.
[image: use ${extensionPath}]

[image: use absolute path]

I don't know why ${extensionPath} turn into '/'.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if extentionPath is a resarved word in setting.json. I also asume that its for your own extention you implement, if so then i recommand you use the Method `vscode.workspace.getConfiguration(...)` it will return the Configuration value from your setting.json. and if you want to update it just use the Method update(context.extentionPath). You can find it in [this Link](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api)  . Also a sample code:

```
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {

    const workbenchConfig = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('workbench')
    const toEdit = workbenchConfig.get('your_config')
    toEdit.update(context.extentionPath); // or the Path you specify

}
```

Comment: Nope.${extensionPath} is built-in variable I think.
When I install this extention,it simultaneously write in setting.json.

Comment: About your suggestion,I'm not sure where I should write the code. In setting.json?